# Keep reading from tcp server until a certain message is received

Tags: bash, shell, tcp, netcat

I have the following code:

```
 echo "about to echo stuff 1";

 echo -e "foo\n" | nc localhost "${ql_server_port}" | while read response; do
         echo "response from server: $response";
         if [[ "$response" == "released" ]]; then
            echo "quicklock: Lock was released.";
            return 0;
         fi
   done;

 echo "about to echo stuff 2";
```

this is what got logged:

> ```
> about to echo stuff 1
> response from server: received_data
> about to echo stuff 2
> ```

I can't figure out why it doesn't keep reading from the netcat connection, seems to stop reading after receiving the first message. Anyone know how to keep reading from the connection?

**My guess is that the pipeline closes down because the echo statement exits?** If that's the case, how to keep it open?

Comment: I asked this question - https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1228

Answer (score 2):

File descriptor redirection to the rescue

```
# make a copy of stdout
exec  3<&1
echo "about to echo stuff 1";

# read from fd 3
{ nc localhost 1234 <3 | while read response; do
    echo "response from server: $response";
    if [[ "$response" == "released" ]]; then
        echo "quicklock: Lock was released."
        break
    fi
done } &

# echo to stdout but redirect to fd 3
echo -e "foo\n" >3
echo -e "bar\n" >3
# close descriptor when done
exec  3<&-
# wait for comm to finish
sleep 2
echo "about to echo stuff 2";
```

Output

```
about to echo stuff 1
response from server: bin
response from server: gar
response from server: released
quicklock: Lock was released.
about to echo stuff 2
```

Comment: yeah I did some research, all you need to do is keep that first process open. echo will die after writing to stdout. if you create a process that will stay alive after writing to stdout, then that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I am looking for a simpler way to do it if possible:

```
     local named_pipe="$HOME/.quicklock/named_pipes/$$";
     mkfifo ${named_pipe};

      tail -f ${named_pipe} | nc localhost "${ql_server_port}" | while read response; do
         echo "response from server: $response";
         if [[ "$response" == "released" ]]; then
            echo "quicklock: Lock was released.";
            return 0;
         fi
      done &
   fi


     echo -e "{\"quicklock\":true}\n" > ${named_pipe}
     wait;
```

is there a way to echo something, but not close the process?